# How to Specify the space left of a table?

Tags: spacing, xtab

In my project I am using the `xtab` package.

```
\usepackage{xtab}

\begin{document}
\def\hsa{\hspace{0.03in}}   
\def\hsb{\hspace{0.05in}}
\def\hsc{\hspace{1.01in}}
\def\hsd{\hspace{0in}}
\begin{xtabular}{llp{0.65in}l}  
    Sáncte  &\textbf{Pá}ule,    &\hsb o\textit{ra}      &\hsd \textit{pro} \hsa \textbf{nó}bis. \\
    Sáncte  &An\textbf{dré}a,   &\hsb o\textit{ra}      &\hsd \textit{pro} \hsa \textbf{nó}bis. \\
    Sáncte  &Ja\textbf{có}be,   &\hsb o\textit{ra}      &\hsd \textit{pro} \hsa \textbf{nó}bis. \\
    Sáncte  &Jo\textbf{án}nes,  &\hsb o\textit{ra}      &\hsd \textit{pro} \hsa \textbf{nó}bis. \\
    Sáncte  &\textbf{Thó}ma,    &\hsb o\textit{ra}      &\hsd \textit{pro} \hsa \textbf{nó}bis. \\
    Sáncte  &Ja\textbf{có}be,   &\hsb o\textit{ra}      &\hsd \textit{pro} \hsa \textbf{nó}bis. \\
    ...
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

Now, I want to adjust the space to the left of the the `xtabular` table.  I *could* add some `\hspace` before the table begins, but if the table is long enough to break across pages, the table part on the following page does not honour the `\space`.  [I've tried](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting) `\parskip` and `\parindent` lengths already to no avail.

How can I modify the space there?

Comment: `\begin{xtabular}{@{\hspace{2cm}llp{0.65in}}` should work (here `2cm` is just a random value, adjust to suit).

Comment: @egreg That's the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the fixed space before the first column specifier.

Here's how I'd typeset the litanies:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xtab}

\newcommand{\ora}{o\textit{ra}}
\newcommand{\orate}{o\textbf{rá}\textit{te}}
\newcommand{\pro}{\textit{pro} \textbf{nó}bis}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some text to show the left margin

\begin{xtabular}{@{\hspace{2cm}}l@{ }l@{ }l@{ }l@{}}
Sáncte & \textbf{Pá}ule,    & \ora   & \pro \\
Sáncte & An\textbf{dré}a,   & \ora   & \pro \\
Sáncte & Ja\textbf{có}be,   & \ora   & \pro \\
Sáncte & Jo\textbf{án}nes,  & \ora   & \pro \\
Sáncte & \textbf{Thó}ma,    & \ora   & \pro \\
Sáncte & Ja\textbf{có}be,   & \ora   & \pro \\
Sáncti & Phi\textbf{lí}ppe et Ja\textbf{có}be & \orate & \pro \\
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

Between columns I use normal interword spaces; the left alignment will take care of correct spacing.

Better using macros as I show.

[image]

Comment: Wow!  Thank you for the advice and the idea for using `\newcommand`!  I wish you would hang out on the #gregorio irc!

Comment: Do I have to leave spaces between `&` and `\ora` in the code like that?  It will work fine without the spaces won't it?

Comment: @BGM Spaces are ignored after `&` by TeX rule and before it by LaTeX implementation.

Comment: That's what I though; so it's just a matter of coding style, then.  Thanks again!